# How to limit one row per user id

Tags: mysql, left-join, inner-join, groupwise-maximum

**I have this table called employeetimesheets:**

```
empsheet_id|employee_id|timesheet_status|last_update
```

The table allows the manager to have access to all the employee time sheets. One employee can have several time sheets. I would like to display *only* the most recent entry per employee. I read [in the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html) I have to write a groupwise-maximum subquery and `left join` with `inner join` but I'm unsure how to go about it here.

**So far this is the query I have:**

```
$sqlempsheets="SELECT * FROM employeetimesheets JOIN employees ON employeetimesheets.employee_id=employees.employee_id WHERE employeetimesheets.timesheet_status='Pending Approval'";
$resultempsheets=mysqli_query($db,$sqlempsheets);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
select *
from employeetimesheets t
join (
    select employee_id,
        max(empsheet_id) as empsheet_id
    from employeetimesheets
    group by employee_id
    ) t2 on t.employee_id = t2.employee_id
    and t.empsheet_id = t2.empsheet_id
join employees e on t.employee_id = e.employee_id
where t.timesheet_status = 'Pending Approval';
```

Or using `left join`:

```
select t.*, e.*
from employeetimesheets t
left join employeetimesheets t2 on t.employee_id = t2.employee_id
    and t.empsheet_id < t2.empsheet_id
join employees e on t.employee_id = e.employee_id
where t.timesheet_status = 'Pending Approval'
    and t2.employee_id is null;
```